# How can I use a custom compiler for my LaTeX document in LaTeX Lab?

Tags: latex, google-docs

I'm using LaTeX, and recently [LaTeX Lab](http://docs.latexlab.org/docs), an online LaTeX interface to Google docs, was released.

For the most part this online LaTeX compiler is great, and I can get a document such as this to compile:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{\LaTeX without extra usepackages}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  I would like to know how to use \LaTeX{} with extra packages.

  % This is a comment; it is not shown in the final output.
  % The following shows a little of the typesetting power of LaTeX
  \begin{align}
    E &= mc^2                              \\
    m &= \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

However, larger documents using more packages don't compile, even though they do on local installations of LaTeX.  An example is below:

```
% 
% This document illustrates using LaTeX. LaTeX2HTML and DVIPDFM together
% for graphics and hyperlinks.
% 
%
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,dvipdfm]{article}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color} 
\usepackage{html}
%
% The lines below to use HYPERREF need to be commented out to get numbering to work 
% in the HTML version. Once commented out, run LaTeX several times, and then LaTeX2HTML:
%
%\usepackage[dvipdfm, latex2html,
%                           colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue,
%                           bookmarks, bookmarksopen, bookmarksnumbered,
%                           pdfauthor={Charles Clayton}]{hyperref}
%
% The command below simplifies the process of including an image. It assumes that the images
% are in a sub-folder called "graphics" in the folder that the .tex document lives in.
% It also assumes a bounding box file created e.g. with EBB exists in the subdirectory.
% If the graphic is (for example) called graph.jpg, then the bounding box file should be graph.bb
% The first parameter is the name of the image, the second the text for the ALT tag.
% Note that for some reason it goes wrong if you use \begin{htmlonly}...\end{htmlonly}
% instead of \html. This "feature" might however change in subsequent versions.
%
\newcommand{\img}[2]{
\begin{makeimage}
\end{makeimage}
\centering
\latex{\includegraphics{graphics/#1}}
\html{\htmladdimg[ALT="#2"]{../graphics/#1}}}
%
% The next two commands are just modified versions of \img
% The first shows how to put a box round things in both the HTML and PDF versions
% The seconds shows how to scale the image.
%
\newcommand{\boxedimg}[2]{
\begin{makeimage}
\end{makeimage}
\centering
\latex{\fbox{\includegraphics{graphics/#1}}}
\html{\htmladdimg[ALT="#2" BORDER="1"]{../graphics/#1}}}
%
\newcommand{\scaledimg}[2]{
\begin{makeimage}
\end{makeimage}
\centering
\latex{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{graphics/#1}}
\html{\htmladdimg[ALT="#2" WIDTH="5cm"]{../graphics/#1}}}
%
%
%
\title{Example Document}
\author{Charles Clayton}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\abstract{
This document includes graphics and hyperlinks and should run correctly through 
both LaTeX2HTML and DVIPDFM. See the document 
\htmladdnormallink{Getting \LaTeX\ and \LaTeX2HTML\ and DVIPDFM to Work Together}
{http://members.tripod.com/charlesclayton/index.htm} for more information.}

\tableofcontents\section{Hyperlinks}

These links should `work' (i.e. be clickable) in both the PDF and HTML documents.
\begin{itemize}
\item A link to an external web page: \htmladdnormallink{Amazon.com}{http://www.amazon.com}
\item A link to the \htmlref{next section}{sec:Gr}
\item A link to the next section, using a standard \verb+\ref+: Section \ref{sec:Gr}. 
To get section numbers you must use the \verb+show_section_numbers+ command line 
option with \LaTeX2HTML. Also, the line that uses the \verb+hyperref+ package must 
be commented out (due to a bug) and LaTeX re-run several times before running \LaTeX2HTML.
\item It does not seem possible to get a single link to e.g. `Section 2', as 
\verb+\ref+ does not work within \verb+\htmlref+ and similar commands. 
One can get nearly there by combining an \verb+\htmlref+ 
and a \verb+\ref+: \htmlref{Section}{sec:Gr} \ref{sec:Gr}.
\item This is an ordinary \verb+\cite+: \cite{ref1}. Note that \verb+\htmlcite+ does not
 seem to work in the PDF version (unlike \verb+\htmlref+ which works in both)
\item This is a reference to equation \ref{eqn1}
\item This is a reference to the \htmlref{same equation}{eqn1} done with \verb+\htmlref+
\end{itemize}

\section{Graphics}
\label{sec:Gr}
The figures in this document demonstrate including a JPEG image in both the PDF and HTML
versions. For details of how to use EPS graphics, see the document
\htmladdnormallink{Getting \LaTeX\ and \LaTeX2HTML\ and DVIPDFM to Work Together}
{http://members.tripod.com/charlesclayton/index.htm}. Notice that
\begin{itemize}
\item the ALT tag is set in the HTML versions;
\item if the \verb+\caption+ comes before the \verb+\includegraphics+, 
the caption will be above the image, otherwise it will be below the image. 
This is only the case in the PDF document, however.
\end{itemize}

\begin{figure}
\img{graphic.jpg}{A graph of some statistical distributions}
\caption{A graphic}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\boxedimg{graphic.jpg}{A boxed graph}
\caption{A boxed graphic}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A scaled graphic. In the PDF version, the caption will be on top of the image}
\scaledimg{graphic.jpg}{A scaled graph}
\end{figure}

\section{Other Remarks}
\begin{itemize}
\item Note that the PDF version has working bookmarks;
\item The author field is also set in the PDF document information;
\item Note the use of a ALT tag in the equation below. 
This provides meaningful alternative text if the equation is not displayed or a tool tip
\end{itemize}
\begin{equation}
\htmlimage{ALT="A fundamental equation"}
\label{eqn1}
e^{i\pi}=-1
\end{equation}


\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ref1} A test bibliography entry.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I would like to use LaTeX Labs to access, edit, and compile latex documents online. Is using a private compiler off of my own server a solution to this problem?  Is there an easier way?  If not, can anyone point me in the correct direction to set this up?  The [main tutorial page for this](http://code.google.com/p/latex-lab/wiki/UsingPrivateCompiler) is blank. (Update: Now there is some description there.)

There are other tutorial pages as well:

- [The Common LaTeX Service Interface](http://clsi.scribtex.com/) (Home page)
- [Common LaTeX Service Interface (CLSI)](http://wiki.github.com/jpallen/clsi/) (Github Wiki)
- [CLSI Request Format](https://github.com/jpallen/clsi/wiki/Request-Format) (Github Wiki)

Comment: I think there are two problems here:
1) how to use the clsi service
2) how you manage the thesis review with your supervisor
I don't think your supervisor is wishing to deal with your LaTeX code. He would review the content of the thesis, instead; in this case, providing him with the pdf is better. Am I wrong?

Comment: You raise a good point I think PDF is the best for my supervisor.  Still there are many other uses for this solution.  What if I am at the library and want to add something to my thesis?  What if I am collaborating with other technical people on a paper?  I work in bioinformatics, so we all program, though we may not all be familiar with the inner workings of latex.  There are many latex documents I would like to be able to access, edit, and compile online.  For now I would be interested in 1) how to use the clsi service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the CLSI, if you are interested in including a few extra packages you can upload them as style documents

> Files -> Upload Files

Then you can include them in your compilation

> Compiler -> Project resources

For example I uploaded the following two files:

> http://www.math.toronto.edu/~drorbn/VasBib/html.sty
>
> http://lx2.saas.hku.hk/Conference/IascAsian05/hkustasc/template/graphicx.sty

and was able to compile the Tex document in the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some documentation on bringing up a CLSI server instance on the CLSI project site:
http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/wiki/InstallAndConfig

For directions on using a custom CLSI environment with LaTeX Lab see the following page:
code.google.com/p/latex-lab/wiki/UsingPrivateCompiler

I would only recommend bringing up a CLSI instance if you're planning to expose a custom, perhaps more powerful, LaTeX compiler, to a set of users. For getting around missing packages i recommend following DW's response.

There will be an option in the near future to use a local TeX Live/MikTeX installation, this way you'll be able to use a custom LaTeX environment without bringing up a CLSI server.